# Screen dark and barely visible after boot

Tags: ubuntu

After booting my Ubuntu 20 laptop, the screen is barely visible and mostly dark. The Ubuntu logo still appears, but afterwards the screen goes dark. How can I resolve this?

Any help would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using nomodeset in Grub seemed to fix the problem. – [watchy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/510428/watchy)